# Convert mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM into date and add minutes

Tags: sql-server, datetime-format

I have date of birth stored in SQL server database as in this **4/23/1988 6:30:00 PM** format. This column has nvarchar format. Now i want to convert this into IST which will add 5.30 hours to this date i.e output should be **4/24/1988** . It has null values also. how to do this ?

Comment: you should use date time data type for storing date time value

Comment: yes but the system was developed by other...now it is connected to live website...cant change it now....i need this only to generate report

Comment: by the way, what is IST ?

Comment: its indian standard time....adding 5.30 hours

Answer (score 1):

Convert() to datetime first before adding the 330 minutes

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, 330, CONVERT(DATETIME, date_of_birth, 101))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,330,cast(date_of_birth AS datetime)) AS DATE)
```

Comment: getting error The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. It has null values also...may b this creating problem

Comment: u can convert the column/variable to datetime cast(@v_strdate AS datetime)

Comment: still getiing same error..tried this    case when um_date_of_birth is null then um_date_of_birth else CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,330,cast(um_date_of_birth AS datetime)) AS DATE) end

Comment: check is there any Invalid date in table column (there is a possibility , bcs it is a varchar field)

Comment: its a large database...thr may b invalid date range values...is thr any way where we can skip invalid dates

Comment: yes, SELECT * FROM table WHERE isdate([date column]) = 0 , try **isdate** function to check the data is a *valid date or not*

Answer (score 0):

Found solution....i skipped results which are null & are not valid.

**Select DATEADD(MINUTE, 330, CONVERT(DATETIME, um_date_of_birth, 101)) from user_master where um_date_of_birth is not null and isdate( um_date_of_birth) <> 0**